# Entity Framework - Create SQL Server database with specified user as DBO

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm currently getting to grips with a basic EF core project, with Microsoft SQL Server (19).
For example, with a very basic example project, the context:

```
public SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext")
{
}

public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add<Configuration>
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("safe"); 
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that when the code-first approach is used, and the application creates the database, the current active user is always provided as the 'dbo' / 'dbowner' user for the database.

We can ensure that any created tables are not in the default schema using

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("safe");
```

But, the problem remains that the default owner of the database ius being set to whoever runs the application.

Is there a way to structure this so that a specific user is given as these roles when creating the datbase? For example, a pre-existing admin user in the SQL server?

Comment: Change the connection string to be ADMIN account if username and password. If your connection string is "Trusted_Connection=True" (windows credentials) you need to be an admin.  If you are running from Visual Studio you are not automatically running As Admin unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but is the connection string the "base("SchoolContext")"?
I'm unsure if Trusted_Connection=True currently, this is from a basic startup project.

Comment: The must be a connection string.  It may be in a config file.  SQL Server has two different types of credentials 1) SQL - username and password 2) Widows Credentials.  When you login to database the credential type is in the login windows.  Trusted_Connection is windows credentials.

Comment: Thank you, I follow - so this setup would mean that an Admin Windows user would be the user assigned to the DBO account in SQL, and would be the dbowner etc?

Comment: When running a c# application in VS it default to the user account (not admin).  When executing the c# application outside VS it will automatically run As Admin (not user account).  So you will not have the issue outside VS.  When using Windows credentials the user login (and group) are forwarded to the SQL Server.  So the database will be giving the group permissions.  Then all users who are part of the Group (or Group Policy) will be given access.  The owner isn't as important as the Group.  The owner is only need to be able to change login properties of the database.

Comment: I see, so as long as the connection string is under the admin user (windows auth), the created database will always have the admin user set as the dbowner?

Comment: Not 100% sure.  I've haven't created a lot of Databases in SQL through a connection string.  Usually I use SQL Server.  You can see the log files using  SSMS under management which will show the login with user and group.  I've used it a number of times to debug connection issues.